# "like box" for facebook events

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I know it's possible to do a "like box" for a facebook page, but is it possible to do something similar for events?
Here's the URL for the like box
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

If i simply change the page url to the event url, I get the error message `Could not retrieve the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in`.

Basically I would like to be able to post something similar on my website saying "these people signed up for XY event."

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a nice plugin idea. However, I can imagine after months/years pass there will be millions of event plugins on web pages whose associated events has long passed.  The like box is relevant practically forever, but events come and go.

Still, you can definitely build your own event box using the Event API:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event

For example, query all `attending` and build a facepile of those users along with the event's info.

Comment: Hmm, looks like there's still some code to figure out, but I think this will take me in the right direction. Thansk!